# Creating objects from a YAML file with method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to save some objects to a YAML file, then load them whenever I need and create some model objects from them. That's easy and direct as loading the file and looping on the objects and create them on the go.

But my problem is that I need to have some fields that are actually method calls. For example:

```
  users:
      -   name: sam
          email: sam@example.com
          status: status_label(1)
          comment: first_occurrence.comment   

      -   name: jane
          email: jane@example.com
          status: status_label(2)
          comment: first_occurrence.comment
```

Those methods are methods on the class I will load the YAML file in and start creating users objects.

In Application model:

```
data = YAML.load_file 'data.ml'
data['users'].each do |key, values|
  User.create values
end
```

that will not evaluate the methods instead will save them as values, how to solve that?

Comment: There is a `seed.rb` for such need

Comment: No, the case here is not related to seeds at all

Comment: These objects will be created every time a new user sign up to the application.

Comment: "Some fields are method calls"? So you need custom serialization?

Comment: Yes, feel free to show how.

Comment: Is `status_label` an instance method or a class method?

Comment: YAML is useful when you're using it for globals and constants and startup values that might occasionally change, but I wouldn't recommend it for anything tied to a user's account. Instead a DB would be better as it'll scale well; Imagine if your code turns out to be the next great internet sensation and you have millions of users and you're trying to read a YAML file to process their accounts. You'll beat your host to pieces.

Comment: @theTinMan I am not using it the way you got it at all, the example above is  not the real case, the real scenario is that I am creating 4 objects when new users sign up, and I wanted to move the data for those 4 objects to a YAML file to be generated from.

Comment: My question is why use YAML for that? Why not use straight Ruby code? YAML is great for some things but it doesn't seem like a good use for this case.

Answer (score 4):

Change the YAML structure so that the values and method calls are distinguished. Something like this will do:

```
users:
-   attributes:
        name: sam
        email: sam@example.com
    properties:
        status: status_label(1)
        comment: first_occurrence.comment
```

In your class use:

```
data = YAML.load_file 'data.ml'
data['users'].each do |key, values|
  u = User.new values['attributes']
  values['properties'].each do |key, property|
    u[key] = instance_eval(property)
    u.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't make sense to do `u.save` inside the loop. Just use `User.create` with a block and do the rest of the logic inside the block; this will set the attributes and automatically save the record at the end.

Comment: Please take the time to use proper grammar and punctuation. I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#writewell.